# Three.js error document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have been looking around, but cannot find people with the same issue. I am at the start of learning to work with Three.js and this (Lynda.com) tutorial has instructed me to write the following php file & javascript code.

The chrome console shows the following error:

```
main.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at init (main.js:25)
at main.js:36
```

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong, I have created a div element with the same id.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
echo "Three JS Course";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Three.js Course</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="webgl"></div>
</body>
```

---

**JS:**

```
function init()
{
//Create scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Create camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    //Perspective
    45,
    //Ratio
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
    //Near clipping distance
    1,
    //Far clipping distance
    1000
);

//Create renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
//Set renderer size
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

//Get element by ID
document.getElementById('webgl').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//Make the renderer render the scene and the camera
renderer.render(
    scene,
    camera
);
}

init();
```

Comment: Where is the JS placed in the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, so I am posting an answer in case anyone else encounters this issue:

Make sure you load your scripts after the HTML file. If *document.getElementById()* tries to acces an element which has not yet been loaded it wont be able to find it!